# Confusion in Eisenbud 1.4.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

On page 29, Eisenbud says,

> Suppose that $S=k[x_1,x_2\cdots x_k]$ is a polynomial ring and that $G$ is represented as a group of linear transformations of the vector space of linear forms of $S$-- that is, we are given a homomorphism of groups $G\rightarrow GL_r(k)$, where we regard the latter group as the group of invertible linear transformations with basis $x_1,x_2\cdots x_r$

I'm good til there. He's representing $G$ by a homomorphism into where $GL_r(k)$ is regarded as acting on elements $span\{x_1,x_2\ldots x_r\}$ (the vector space of linear forms) through their representation under the basis $\{x_1,x_2\ldots x_r\}$ But then he says,

> If $G$ is $SL_n(k)$ or $GL_n(k)$ we suppose further that the matrices $g\in G$ act on $k^r$ as matrices whose entries are rational functions of the entries of $g$; such a representation of $G$ is called rational

I'm not sure what the second mention of matrices is referring to? Is it referring to the elements of $k^r$? And if so, how are we describing the entries of $k^r$ as rational functions of the entries of $g$? If I fix a matrix $g\in G$ then what does it mean to write an element of $k^r$ as a matrix whose entries are rational functions of the entries of $g$? If the second mention of matrices is referring to $g$ then how are we defining $g$ in terms of rational functions of the entries of $g$ (that makes no sense to me)? If it's neither of these, then... it'd be great if someone could just take that part piece by piece. Because, in that case, my understanding of it is way way off. I can't see a way where it's referring to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What he is describing here is the requirement that a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ into a homomorphism of algebraic groups. Since we care about algebraic data, it makes sense that a representation of a group in this context be some sort of algebraic map in addition to being, abstractly a homomorphism.

Consider the $G = \mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ case. Any element $g \in G$ can be written in matrix coordinates $x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn}$:
$$g = \begin{pmatrix} 
 x_{11}& \dotsb & x_{1n} \\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_{n1} & \dots & x_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}$$
What we are requiring is that the homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{GL}_{r}(k)$ is of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
 x_{11}& \dotsb & x_{1n} \\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_{n1} & \dots & x_{nn}
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
f_{11}(x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn}) &\dotsb & f_{1r}(x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn})\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
f_{r1}(x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn}) &\dotsb & f_{rr}(x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn})
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where each of the functions $f_{ij}$ are rational functions in the variables $x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn}$.

Compare this to the case of a Lie group homomorphism, if you are familiar with this: the point is that you want the homomorphism to not only be be an abstract homomorphism of groups, but also that this homomorphism defines a smooth map between manifolds. This is exactly the same idea with "smooth" replaced by "algebraic" and "manifold" by "variety."

Comment: So the algebraic variety $GL_n(k)$ sits inside of $k^{n^2}$ and $GL_r(k)$ sits inside of $k^{r^2}$ and the group homomorphism is also a rational map between algebraic varieties? I'm just making sure because I am not familiar with Lie groups. I've heard of them, but I don't know what they are.

Comment: @UnknownUnknown2 Yes, that is exactly what is being required (though note that $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ is only a quasi-affine variety, being an open subset of $k^{n^2}$ rather than a closed one).

Comment: Cool. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n\neq r$, in general.

What that means is that you are dealing with an homomorphism
$$
\phi:{\rm GL}_n(K)\longrightarrow{\rm GL}_r(K)
$$
and the condition is that the entries of $\phi(g)$ are rational functions of those of $g$.

Simplest case: $n$ any, $r=1$, $\phi=\det$.